# callablestatement.execute() returns an empty resultset if MS SQL preocedure contains CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I use Callablestatement class `execute()` method to call MS SQL procedure.

I call  MS SQL procedure which contains the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #PrevOver (ClCode char(6) NULL , 
ContrNum char(4) NULL , 
OverContr smallint NULL, 
GenerNum tinyint NULL )
```

Table is used as a temporary data storage

If I drop the statement above and re-write procedure that way that it returns data with select statement only - everything works fine. The problem is that some procedures require "CREATE TABLE" statement.

I connect with "sa" permits, so it shouldn't be permission problem.
I use jtds

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following parameters to procedure body:

*SET NOCOUNT ON

SET FMTONLY OFF*